# In after effects can you give 2d images thickness when arranging them in 3d?

Tags: adobe-after-effects

In after effects I have some PNGs which are arranged in 3d. When they are rotated 90 degrees they all but disappear because they have no thickness. Is there a way to give them thickness?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: No

Long answer: You can if you really, really want to but it will either cost money for a plug-in or time in order to hack about and get it working. See my post on the adobe forums for more info: forums.adobe.com/message/2550842#2550842

Answer (score 0):

You can use displacement maps and the plugin FreeForm (included in CS5) to curve your layers..

Best example of this I've seen is: [jelescu_tudor: 3D-from-2D-image_AE](http://library.creativecow.net/jelescu_tudor/3D-from-2D-image_AE/1)